# Playwright With TypeScript , How to click on SVG componanr Donut Chart

Tags: typescript

I need to do mouse over to get the mouse over display text value of Donut Chart.

Iam trying to click on SVG Component Donut Chart using TypeScript

```
await this.NO_VUL_SECTION_OVER.hover({ force: true });
```

NO_VUL_SECTION_OVER is my xpath locaator.

But its not happening , or i need to do mouse over to get the mouse over display text value.

Iam trying to click on SVG Component Donut Chart using TypeScript

```
await this.NO_VUL_SECTION_OVER.hover({ force: true });
```

but it not happening.